# componentDidMount function not working properly

Tags: reactjs

So I'm creating a simple React app that fetches data from a JSON API server and displays it in a table. Here is the code for the main component:

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import Table from "./Table.js"

class Main extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            array: null
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Table array={this.state.array} />
            </div>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Checking");
        fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1exld0")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({ array: data })
            });
    }
}

export default Main;
```

However when I run the app the table is not being rendered. This has something to do with the componentDidMount function not working properly because I have a line of code:

```
console.log("Checking")
```

and the console doesn't log anything.

Can anyone help?

Edit: Here are the Table and TableRow components:

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import TableRow from "./TableRow.js";

class Table extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={

        }
    }

    render(){
        var self=this;
        var items=this.props.array.map(function(item, index){
            return <TableRow obj={item} key={index}/>
        })

        return(
            <table>
                {items}
            </table>
        )
    }
}

export default Table
```

/

```
import React, {Component} from "react"

class TableRow extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={

        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <tr><td>{this.props.obj.color}</td><td>{this.props.obj.value}</td></tr>
        )
    }
}

export default TableRow
```

And here is the error that I am being given when I run the app in the browser:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null:
var items=this.props.array.map(function(item, index){
```

Comment: Could you include the `Table` component? Your `componentDidMount` looks fine.

Comment: if console is not logging "checking", then your Main component is not being mounted. You have to check where you are using Main component, that it is used properly

Comment: Are you sure that your `Main` component is actually rendered? Please provide the code that renders your `Main` component.

Comment: The component is being mounted. I know this because it gives me the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null in this line of code: var items=this.props.array.map(function(item, index){

Comment: @DavidDaniels, where you get this error? Inside the Main component? or the parent?

Comment: Inside the table component

Comment: Are you using Server Side rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the array to the empty array instead of null in the Main constructor. There will be an initial render cycle before the async data is loaded, and that crashes since you cannot map over a null array.

Comment: Thank you very much. This error has been giving me headaches for almost 2 hours. You deserve a crown sir!

Comment: Can you see the console.log now?

Comment: Yes everything is fixed!

Answer (score -1):

move componentDidMount() out of the render() method , that will fix it

Comment: Its not inside the render method

Comment: Our maybe your component isn't being mounted at all